# concatenate 2 lists in a certain order

Tags: python-3.x, list, concatenation

I want to do something called lacing.
I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = ['4,5', '5,3', '1,2', '0,4', '6,2']
list2 = ['1,3', '6,4', '8,8']
```

I want my output to look like this

```
list3 = ['4,5','1,3','5,3','6,4','1,2','8,8','0,4', '6,2']
```

So the new list should have the first element of the first list, then the first element of the second list followed by the second element of the first list, then the second element in the second list.
Finally, if they are not equal, I would like to dump the rest at the end of the new list.

I tried using

```
for l1,l2 in zip(one_final,three_final):
    list3.append(l1+l2)
```

but I got this back

```
['4,50,6', '5,33,1', '1,27,8', '0,46,6', '6,27,7']
```

How can I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: Use `zip_longest` from itertools

Comment: list3.extend([l1,l2]) ... or.. list3.append(l1);list3.append(l2) .. or so many other possibiiltes - zip will only work up to the shorter list last element though

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
list1 = ['4,5', '5,3', '1,2', '0,4', '6,2']
list2 = ['1,3', '6,4', '8,8']
```

You can do:

```
import itertools as it
>>> [e for t in it.zip_longest(list1, list2) for e in t if e is not None]
['4,5', '1,3', '5,3', '6,4', '1,2', '8,8', '0,4', '6,2']
```

If there is a possibility of `None` as legit data in your lists, use a sentinel object instead:

```
sentinel=object()
[e for t in it.zip_longest(list1, list2, fillvalue=sentinel) for e in t if e is not sentinel]
```